# amCharts 4 Geo Heat Map - how to add logic to tooltip?

Tags: amcharts

The amCharts 4 Geo Heat Map example (https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/yvdwrR) defines the tooltip text thus:

```
var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}: {value.value.formatNumber('#.0')}";
```

So, for example, the tooltip displays "United States: 78.8". If the US entry ({id: "US", value: 78.797}), is removed from `polygonSeries.data` the tooltip displays "United States:". Is there a way to add logic so that the tooltip shows "United States: No data"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `tooltipText` adapter to check your data and determine what value to return, for example:

```
polygonTemplate.adapter.add("tooltipText", function(text, ev) {
  if (!ev.dataItem.dataContext.value) {
    return "{name}: No value";
  }
  return text;
})
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5d8b68b90110de727868577df8a8d190/?editors=0010)